# How to bypass the PHP strip_tags function

Tags: javascript, php, css, xss, strip-tags

Consider the following situation. A regular user posts a text-comment to a website.

Then

1. the text gets stored in a php variable.
2. strip_tags is called with the variable as its argument.
3. the comment is displayed, saved or whatever

Like so

```
<?php 
 $xss='" style="a:b;margin-top:-1000px;margin-left:-100px;width:4000px;height:4000px;display:block;" onmouseover=alert(1); a="';
 $xss=strip_tags($xss);
 print '<input name="123" value="'.$xss.'"/>';
?>
```

And my exact question is: How do I change the `$xss` string so when

`print '<a href="#">'.$xss.'</a>';` is called instead of
`print '<input name="123" value="'.$xss.'"/>';` the page executes `alert(1)`  in some way?

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but the value of `$xss` in your example shouldn't change after running through `strip_tags()`, since there's no tags in the string to strip.